# PHP $_GET to same page from form submit

Tags: php, forms, get

I am trying to use the $_GET value to load on the same page as my form instead of opening a new page. For example, the form is on my page "products.php" and I want the form to filter database results by type of product. So on submit, it should redirect to "products.php?type=tee".

If I manually type it in the address bar it works like a charm, but I can't get the form submit to load it.

Here's my code (Update: Here's the whole file, using require_once into a basic html5 template):

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    //Populate Items to Show
    function populateItems($result){ 
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                if ($row['available']){
                    echo '<li><img src="', $row['image'], '" />';
                    echo '<ul>';
                        echo '<li><h1>', $row['product'], '</h1></li>';
                        echo '<li><h2>', $row['description'], '</h2></li>';
                        echo '<li><h3>$', $row['price'], '</h3></li>';
                    echo '</ul>';
                    echo '</li>';
                }
            }

            $result->free();
    }

    //Create Item List
     echo '<ul class="item">';

    //Create Filter
    echo '<li id="filter">';
    if ($result = $conn->query("SELECT DISTINCT type FROM products")){
        echo 'Filter Results By: <form method="GET" action="', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], '">';
        echo '<select>';
        echo '<option>Show All</option>';
        while ($type = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            echo '<option name="type" value="', $type['type'], '">', $type['type'], 's</option>';
        }
        echo '</select>';
        echo '<input type="submit" value="Go" />';
        echo '</form>';
    }
    echo '</li>';

    //Find if Filter Exists
    if (isset($_GET['type']) && $_GET['type'] != "" ){
        $gettype = $_GET['type'];
        $filtertype = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE type='$gettype'");
        $count = $filtertype->num_rows;
        if ($count <= 0){
            populateItems($conn->query("SELECT * FROM products"));
        }else{
            populateItems($conn->query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE type='$gettype'"));
        }
    }else{
        populateItems($conn->query("SELECT * FROM products"));
    }

    //End Item List
    echo '</ul>';
?>
```

I've searched all over and haven't found anything that quite answers my question... Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Change method to get

Comment: Sidenote: You're actually better off using POST (and safer) instead of GET (if not taking into account possible injection), and using POST variables in your PHP/SQL, unless a GET is what you "need".

Comment: As per your edit changing POST to GET, show the rest of your PHP then, the problem is obviously in there. Here, add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything which may signal undefined index warnings.

Comment: Your `<select>` isn't named neither, so that could be an additional factor, or is that your full code?

Comment: @Fred -ii- That did it! I named my <select> and now it's working exactly how I wanted it to. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkLittle You're welcome Mark. However, the answer you accepted makes no mention of your select no being named.

Comment: @MarkLittle I've posted an answer below, which reflects the actual issue with your edited code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your `<option name="type"` named when it should be the `<select>`.

`<option>` does not have named attributes.

Therefore, you need to remove `name="type"` from your `<option>` and change your `<select>` to `<select name="type">`

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<form method="post" action="">
```

To

```
<form method="get" action="">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the Method if you want to use `GET`! Like this:

```
...<form method="get" action="">...
```

Comment: I'm not sure why the code I shared still said "post". I messed around with that earlier to see what would happen, but when I went back into my editor to change it back to "get", it was already there. I think it has something to do with the action, but nothing I'm trying there is working. It's just simply reloading the page as products.php with no ?type=whatever

Comment: @MarkLittle If the posted code above is not in the file `products.php` then change the action to: `action="products.php"`

Comment: @MarkLittle Also i think you want to add the att `value` to your options like: `<option value="test">test</option>`